# Reading file from src/main/resources as File?

Tags: java, scala

My project structure looks like

```
src/main/resources/bluecoat_100_lines.log
```

My code looks like

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("logprocessor")

    val file: File = new File("src/main/resources/bluecoat_100_lines.log")

    val logFile = LogFile(file, system)
    logFile.process()
  }
}
```

and

```
object LogFile {
  def apply(file: File, system: ActorSystem) = new LogFile(file, system)
}

class LogFile(file: File, system: ActorSystem) {
  val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass))

  def process() = {
    Predef.assert(file.exists(), "log file must exists")
    logger.debug(s"processing $file")
  }
}
```

Currently I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: log file must exists
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)
    at com.learner.processor.LogFile.process(LogFile.scala:24)
    at com.learner.logprocessor.Main$.main(Main.scala:15)
    at com.learner.logprocessor.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

How do I open it resources file as `File` and not as `InputStream` as `getClass.getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: You don't; you use the stream.

Comment: That is a not intended usage. Resources are meant to be read-only and possibly packed in a jar or such. You could store an original file as such, and copy it with Java getResource/getResourceAsStream to an external file. And use that.

Answer (score -3):

```
File f = new File("your file directory here.");
```

Also, where is your `getClass.getResourceAsStream`